# Is there a single origin for the connection between the beguiled and gullible?

Tags: etymology, linguistics, historical-change

I was thinking that there might be a connection between beguiled and gullible because of the similarity of their letters and their meaning. 
I believe there's a connection because gullible means easily beguiled or deceived and beguiled means to deceive.

So that led me to my research about if be-**guile-ible** got shortened to **gullible** at some point in history. However any other connection that is found is acceptable.

The origin of beguiled (through guile) by Google leads the origin being from old Norse
[image: the origin of beguiled by Google leads the origin being from old Norse]

the origin of gullible leads only to the 19th century by Google
[image: the origin of global leads to the 19th century by Google]

Is there a single, deeper origin for the connection between beguiled and gullible?

Comment: So what does the entry for *gull* say? Does that have anything in common with *guile*? (I would suggest, though, that a real dictionary with citable etymologies would be preferable to Google, which doesn't give any citations at all.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach it says the origin of gull is late Middle English "gull." I thought it a little repetitive to put it in the question.